# How can I emulate jQuery's trigger()?

Tags: javascript

I have a small script I am writing (to ignore the hundreds of stupid requests I get on FaceBook).

```
var inputs = document
              .getElementById('contentArea')
              .getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0, inputsLength = inputs.length; i < inputsLength; i++) {

    if (inputs[i].value !== 'Ignore') {
        continue;
    }

    // What I would do with jQuery, if inputs[i] was a jQuery object.
    inputs[i].click();

}
```

So basically I want to call the click event on all these ignore buttons, and let FaceBook's AJAX do the rest.

How can I emulate the click without jQuery? I have Googled but haven't found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.click()` is a method of `HTMLInputElement`s in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement#Methods) (not sure if in other browsers too).

Another way, that should work in other browsers too, is using [`document.createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent):

```
var inputs = document
              .getElementById('contentArea')
              .getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0, inputsLength = inputs.length; i < inputsLength; i++) {

    if (inputs[i].value !== 'Ignore') {
        continue;
    }
    // maybe it is enough to create it only once before the the loop, don't know
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    inputs[i].dispatchEvent(evt);

}
```

Of course one would capsulate this in function to make it reusable ;)

Comment: +1, and I'm going to mark it accepted as I learned something (`document.createEvent()`). In this case, I wouldn't encapsulate it, because I ran it straight in my console, once only =}. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried that code above (using `click()`) and it worked in my Firefox.

So I guess the answer is, *do it just like jQuery*.

The final code is...

```
var inputs = document
             .getElementById('contentArea')
             .getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0, inputsLength = inputs.length; i < inputsLength; i++) {

    if (inputs[i].name !== 'actions[reject]') {
        continue;
    }

    inputs[i].click();

}
```